# How to generate a lists of lists or nested from user input while outputting amount of times a word is stated?

Tags: python, list, indexing, nested-lists

So far I have been able to create a function that asks the user to type a message and when the user inputs a message for example (nice day today #running #marathon) python outputs [running marathon]. However when it comes to the 2nd function under the output I want to create a lists of lists and how many times the particular word is said. A prime example would be input="Nice day #running #10k #power #running" and the final output would be [running,10k, power, running] and [[running,2],[10k,1],[power,1]]. I know I have to create a new list and use the result function.

```
import sys

def labeled():
 while(True):
    result = input("Enter a message or type q to end:")
    lstA =[]
    if result =='q':
        break
        print(lstA)
    else:
        for i in result.split():
            if "#" in i:
                lstA.append(i[1:])
                continue
        print(lstA)
                
def tabulated():
new_l=[]
result=[]

labeled()
tabulated()
```

Comment: Getting syntax error : for i in result.split() . please correct your code

Comment: Your expected output isn't clear, why isn't `running` `2` and `power` `1`? And what happened to `marathon`?

Comment: Might be worth looking at [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: just fixed the errors and gave a brief explantation

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED: If you want your tabulated() function to call your labeled function, you have a couple of different options for structuring your code:

Option 1: The labeled() function only queries the user once, then both prints and returns the resulting lstA.  The tabulated() function calls the labeled() function, gets the returned output and processes it into the desired list of lists:

```
def labeled():
    lstA = []
    result = input("Enter a message or type q to end: ")
    if result == "q":
        return False
    for i in result.split():
        if "#" in i:
            lstA.append(i[1:])
    print(f'labeled output: {lstA}')
    return lstA

def tabulated():
    dic = {}
    for item in labeled():
        if item not in dic:
            dic[item] = 1
        else:
            dic[item] += 1
    list_of_lists = [[a,b] for a,b in dic.items()]
    print(list_of_lists)

tabulated()

#output:
Enter a message or type q to end: Nice day #running #10k #power #running
labeled output: ['running', '10k', 'power', 'running']
[['running', 2], ['10k', 1], ['power', 1]]
```

Option 2: The labeled() function queries the user multiple times as per your code. It not only prints lstA each time, but also appends each lstA into an aggregate list of lists. When the while loop is exited, it returns this aggregate list. When the tabulated function() calls the labeled function, it reads through the aggregate list item by item (line by line) and prints a desired list_of_list output for each line that the user had entered.

```
def labeled():
    aggregate_list = []
    while(True):
        lstA = []
        result = input("Enter a message or type q to end: ")
        if result =='q':
            break
        else:
            for i in result.split():
                if "#" in i:
                    lstA.append(i[1:])
            print(f'labeled output: {lstA}')
            aggregate_list.append(lstA)
    return aggregate_list

def tabulated():
    for sentence in labeled():
        dic = {}
        for item in sentence:
            if item not in dic:
                dic[item] = 1
            else:
                dic[item] += 1
        list_of_lists = [[a,b] for a,b in dic.items()]
        print(list_of_lists)

tabulated()

#output:
Enter a message or type q to end: Nice day #running #10k #power #running
labeled output: ['running', '10k', 'power', 'running']
Enter a message or type q to end: Great to #see #you and #see #your #dad
labeled output: ['see', 'you', 'see', 'your', 'dad']
Enter a message or type q to end: q
[['running', 2], ['10k', 1], ['power', 1]]
[['see', 2], ['you', 1], ['your', 1], ['dad', 1]]
```

Comment: This is very helpful! However is there a way I can use the tabulated function which receives the list in the labeled function but generate a list of lists of the unique words the received list have the amount of times the word appeared in the original list received.

Comment: In order to do that, your labeled function would have to return a value.  As it is, it's just printing it.

Comment: Gotcha so under the labeled function would I just put return (lstA) instead of print(lstA) as shown in my original code?  I want my labeled function to just take the message in and put in a list with the  words with the hashtags only and for the tabulated function to generate a list of lists using the labeled function and say how many times that hashtagged function was used.

Comment: Do you need the infinite loop then? If you get rid of the while loop, you can return a list in the labeled() function. The tabulated() function can then call the labeled function and process its output to return or print the resulting list of lists.

Comment: See my updated answer.  It covers all the bases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sys

def labeled():
 while(True):
    result = input("Enter a message or type q to end:")
    lstA = []
    if result =='q':
        break
        print(lstA)
    else:
        for i in result.split():
            if "#" in i:
                lstA.append(i[1:])
                continue
        dictofwords = {}
        for i in lstA:
            if not i in dictofwords:
                dictofwords[f'{i}'] = 1
            else:
                dictofwords[f'{i}'] = dictofwords[f'{i}'] + 1
        print(lstA)
        print(dictofwords)

def tabulated():
    new_l=[]
    result=[]

    labeled()
    tabulated()
```

I didn't actually make a list of lists, but rather a dictionary. I then iterated over the first list, and -

- If the element did not appear in the dictionary, add it with the corresponding value of "1"
- If the element did appear in the dictionary, simply increase its corresponding value

Comment: Gotcha so under the labeled function would I just put return (lstA) instead of print(lstA) as shown in my original code? I want my labeled function to just take the message in and put in a list with the words with the hashtags only and for the tabulated function to generate a list of lists using the labeled function and say how many times that hashtagged function was used

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
sample = "Nice day #running #10k #power #running"

def process_input(string, key_char = "#"):

    # Creating a clean list of keywords by a given target character.
    base_list = [i.replace(f"{key_char}", "") for i in string.split(" ") if i[0] == f"{key_char}"]

    # We can use the list.count() function on a set of keywords
    # to return the instance of each word within a given string.
    word_count_list = [[w, base_list.count(w)] for w in set(base_list)]

    return base_list, word_count_list
```

Output of `process_input(sample)`:

```
(['running', '10k', 'power', 'running'],
 [['power', 1], ['running', 2], ['10k', 1]])
```